# Find-dired: Mini-Buffer prompts "Run find in dir" instead of "Run find (with args)"

Tags: emacs

I'm following a tutorial on searching and finding in emacs. (I'm running it on windows.)

The guy types:
    `Find-dired` 
while in Mini-Buffer. As a consequence the Mini-Buffer prompts:
    `Run find in directory`.
Thus far I get the same result.

But then he types something to get the Mini-Buffer prompt
    `Run find (with args)`
and I don't know what he typed to get this result.

Does anybody know how to get `Run find (with args)` after typing `Find-dired`?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear, and so it risks being closed. Specify just what you are doing, step by step, preferably starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file). Say what you see and what you expected to see instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, that's just what `find-dired` does. First it prompts you for a directory, and then it prompts you for the `find` command arguments:

```
(interactive (list (read-directory-name "Run find in directory: " nil "" t)
                   (read-string "Run find (with args): " find-args '(find-args-history . 1))))
```

`C-h f find-dired` tells you what the command does and what its arguments are. It tells you that there are two arguments: a directory and the arguments to pass to command `find`.

```
find-dired is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
‘find-dired.el’.

(find-dired DIR ARGS)

Run ‘find’ and go into Dired mode on a buffer of the output.
The command run (after changing into DIR) is essentially

find . \( ARGS \) -ls

except that the car of the variable ‘find-ls-option’ specifies what to
use in place of "-ls" as the final argument.
```

Comment: You're right. Path is the first of two arguments and you simply have to press RET after specifying the path.
I'm completely new to both emacs and lisp I'm still a bit lost, so it'll take some time to fully understand you're whole answer but thanks!

To all those who are also new to Emacs and running it on Windows 10. If find/grep don't work (even if you understand the syntax) try installing and running Emacs from bash. In my case it did the trick.